# Where to find all the properties and methods of a specified class in a Gradle plugin?

Tags: android, groovy, gradle

I'm new to Gradle, forgive me if I describe the question unclearly.

After read the [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide), I still have something confused. The most important question is how do I know all the properties and methods of a specified class?

For example, a `BuildType` class ,  it has default instances such as `debug`,`realease`.

The user guide just list a few properties of a class. I want to access a full specification of a class.

I didn't find a API reference doc about android plugin in somewhere yet. Maybe there is also a help command of gradle, but I didn't figure out yet too.

Please help me to figure out this.

Comment: Not sure if it's what you're looking for, [but the javadocs are here](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/javadoc/org/gradle/nativebinaries/BuildType.html)

Comment: I think it's not what I need, because the official gradle doc don't have the properties of BuildType that mentioned in [Gradle Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Types) such as `runProguard`,`versionNameSuffix`, and I don't find the other class type such as `ProductFlavor` too. But thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google release the official document now.

http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/

Answer (score 0):

Gradle's public API is documented in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html), and the Javadoc/Groovydoc linked to from there.

I'm not aware of an equivalent document for the Gradle Android Plugin, but at the very least there is the [Gradle Android Plugin User Guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide).